# Django "no module named myapp.models"

Tags: python, django, module

I should note that there is an `__init __.py` file in the application directory.

I believe I know the source of the error. It seems to lie in the application's `views.py` file.

```
from tbg.myapp.models import Document
from tbg.myapp.forms import DocumentForm
```

Showing you as little as possible, this is a part of what I imported. I observe that if I remove the `tbg`, for example, the error will alter to `no module named myapp`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please have a look into your settings.py file, have you included the app in the INSTALLED_APPS, with a proper name.

Comment: Yes, the app name is in there. I have it as simply "myapp". If I change it to "tbg.myapp", tbg is the project name, then the server immediately crashes, saying "no module named myapp" again.

Comment: Can you please let me know the directory structure of your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `tbg` is the name of your project, your project's directory structure should be something like below:

```
tbg/  # your project's main folder
 |-- tbg/  # inner tbg folder which contains settings, urls, etc.
 |      __init__.py, settings.py, etc.
 |-- myapp/
        models.py, etc.
```

So when you are writing `from tbg.myapp.models import Document`, you are referring to the `tbg` folder inside your project's main folder. As this `tbg` folder doesn't have `myapp` folder, you are getting an error.

To fix this, write `from myapp.models import Document`.

Comment: Sorry, the error was elsewhere. It was in my urls.py, but the reason is the same, so I will mark your answer as correct.